# css intimated image and fixed background

Tags: html, css

This is css code for the banner that I have on my website I wanna add png image on top of this banner that should animate nicely ( like zoom in-out ) ( like a heartbeat )

https://www.gettwitterretweet.com/css/images/social.png (png image )

```
.product-page {
  background: url('../img/people.jpg') repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  border-bottom: none !important;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  padding: 80px 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can do this way check this solution just you need to update the background image where I used the background color

```css
.product-page {
padding: 50px;
background-color: green; 
/* background: url('../img/people.jpg') repeat; */ 
transition: transform .2s; /* Animation */
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
margin: 0 auto;
background-size: cover;
border-bottom: none !important;
background-attachment: fixed;
padding: 80px 0;
}

.product-page:hover {
    transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="product-page"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this you can manage the duration how much you want.

```css
@keyframes zoominout {
    0% {
        transform: scale(1,1);
    }
    50% {
        transform: scale(1.1,1.1);
    }
    100% {
        transform: scale(1,1);
    }
}

.wrapper img {
 animation: zoominout 1s infinite ;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper"><img class="image" src="https://www.gettwitterretweet.com/css/images/social.png"></div>
```

Comment: i used this code but i like your code as well thank for the help  .product-page:before,.product-page:after{     
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 510px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
  animation-name: stretch;
  animation-duration: 1.4s; 
  animation-timing-function: ease-out; 
  animation-delay: 0.1s;
  animation-direction: alternate;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-fill-mode: none;
  animation-play-state: running;
}
    
   @keyframes stretch {
  0% {
    transform: scale(.98);
}

Comment: @Krish cj If my code is useful to you upvote my answer :)